# Is there a way to make all your repositories / repos in GitHub Private from commandline or git? Windows

Tags: git, github, repository, github-api

Is there a way to make all your repositories / repos in GitHub Public from commandline or git on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) program. Specifically:

```
gh repo edit your/repository --visibility=private
```

Comment: My question about how to set all the repos with one command

Comment: I doubt such a bespoke command exists. Sounds like you need to write a script to query GitHub’s api, and do that once for each of them then.

Comment: I see. In that case, as @AD7six mentioned, you'll need to write a small script. I don't have access to a Windows machine so I can't say exactly what such a script would look like, but the github CLI has a `gh repo list` command that should give you all you need write one.